# Xamarin Forms Background Image not showing up on android and not scaling correctly on iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm trying to set my image as a background for my app using BackgroundImage = "background.jpg", but I can't seem to scale it in any way in order to fit the whole image into the app, also, it doesn't show up at all on android. Here is the code and background image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage Padding="0, 40, 0, 0" 
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="RoseySports.Login_Page" 
             BackgroundImage="Background.jpg">


        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Label Text="Email" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Entry Keyboard="Email" WidthRequest="300" x:Name="email"/>


                <Label Text="Password" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Entry IsPassword="true" WidthRequest="300" x:Name="password"/>

            <Button Text="Login" x:Name="login" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" TextColor="Navy"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[background.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1kXT.jpg)  [ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S84bf.png)  [adroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC4RA.png)

Comment: I believe Android does not let you have the name of the resource as a capital letter. so change your resource name to background.jpg from Background.jpg

Comment: What I usually do to make the image set correctly is use an Image above the StackLayout and use its Aspect property to set accordingly. Make sure you wrap everything in a Grid

Comment: Thanks @AbsoluteSith just realized I typed it in with a capital letter. Works on android now. Working on the aspect now

Comment: I just got a weird error. So when the file name is with a capital B (Background.jpg), it works on iOS, but doesn't work on android. And if it's with a lower case b (background.jpg) it works on android and gives the error "System.ArgumentNullException has been thrown. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: image" on iOS

Comment: Make sure your ios has an image called background.jpg and not Background.jpg

Comment: I checked, but the file is called "background.jpg" not  "Background.jpg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working by using this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="RoseySports.Login_Page">  

        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">


        <StackLayout Padding="0, 40, 0, 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">

        <Label Text="Email" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
        <Entry Keyboard="Email" WidthRequest="300" x:Name="email"/>


                <Label Text="Password" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
                <Entry IsPassword="true" WidthRequest="300" x:Name="password"/>

            <Button Text="Login" x:Name="login" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" TextColor="Navy"/>

    </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.To use BackgroundImage property **BackgroundImage="Background.jpg"** in IOS you need to add the required image to an IOS asset catalog. Xamarin.Forms WILL NOT load an image into the BackgroundImage property when it is located in the Resources folder as for versions of IOS pre 7.
Read more for IOS asset catalog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=vswin).

2.You can also achieve this using **Grid**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Image Aspect="AspectFill" x:Name="BGImageLogin" Source="Background.jpg" />
        <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout >
            <Entry Placeholder="Username"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Password"
                      IsPassword="True"/>
            <Button Text="Login""/>
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```